# How to get rid of surrounding quotes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems with weird behaviour in RoR. I'm having a Hash that i'm converting to json using `to_json()` like so:

```
data = Hash.new
# ...
data = data.to_json()
```

This code appears inside a model class. Basically, I'm converting the hash to JSON when saving to database. The problem is, the string gets saved to database with its surrounding quotes. For example, saving an empty hash results in: `"{}"`. This quoted string fails to parse when loading from the database.

How do I get rid of the quotes?

The code is:

```
def do_before_save
  @_data = self.data
  self.data = self.data.to_json()
end
```

EDIT:
Due to confusions, I'm showing my entire model class

```
require 'json'
class User::User < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_find { |user|
        user.data = JSON.parse(user.data)
    }
    after_initialize { |user|
        self.data = Hash.new unless self.data
    }
    before_save :do_before_save
    after_save :do_after_save
    private
        def do_before_save
            @_data = self.data
            self.data = self.data.to_json()
        end
        def do_after_save
            self.data = @_data
        end
end
```

The `data` field is `TEXT` in mysql.

Comment: Aren't you calling `.to_json` twice on the same data?

Comment: Have you tried not to call `to_json`? Chances are that Rails will handle the conversion to and from JSON for you.

Comment: yes, i seems you are calling `to_json` twice

Comment: No I'm calling it once. The function is the one that's set on the `before_save` callback. It gets called automatically.

Comment: @trinopoty: in that case, you don't parse it when you load the object. And so next time you try to save the object, you jsonify it again, producing this result.

Comment: Also check the "two subsequent saves" hypothesis. A [mcve] will be of great help.

Comment: Finally found the problem, ActiveRecord is the one that is converting the Hash to String. So in `before_save` the `data` field is already a string. I've changed my method entirely to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm willing to bet money that this is the result of you calling `.to_json` on the same data twice (without parsing it in between). I've had a fair share of these problems before I devised a rule: "don't mutate data in a lossy way like this".

If your original data was `{}`, then first `.to_json` would produce `"{}"`. But if you were to jsonify it again, you'd get `"\"{}\""` because a string is a valid json data type.

I suggest that you put a breakpoint in your before_save filter and see who's calling it the second time and why.

#### Update

"call `.to_json` twice" is a general description and can also mean that there are two subsequent saves on the same object, and since `self.data` is reassigned, this leads to data corruption. (thanks, @mudasobwa)

Comment: 5 bucks from me

Comment: Add a comment, that there are probably two subsequent saves, and since `self.data` is reassigned on each...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your model's database field **type**.

If the field is string type (like VARCHAR or TEXT) it should be stored as string (no need to get rid of the quotes - they are fine). Make sure calling `to_json` once.

If the field is Postgres JSON type, then you can just assign a hash to the model's field, no need to call `to_json` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving hash as a JSON string in a varchar column you can use [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) to handle marshalling/unmarshaling the data:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :foo, JSON
end
```

Knowing exactly when to convert the data in the lifecycle of a record is actually quite a bit harder than your naive implementation. So don't reinvent the wheel.

However a huge drawback is that the data cannot be queried in the DB*. If you are using [Postgres](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) or MySQL you can instead use a JSON or JSONB (postgres only) column type which allows querying. This example is from the Rails guide docs:

```
# db/migrate/20131220144913_create_events.rb
create_table :events do |t|
  t.json 'payload'
end

# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
end

# Usage
Event.create(payload: { kind: "user_renamed", change: ["jack", "john"]})

event = Event.first
event.payload # => {"kind"=>"user_renamed", "change"=>["jack", "john"]}

## Query based on JSON document
# The -> operator returns the original JSON type (which might be an object), whereas ->> returns text
Event.where("payload->>'kind' = ?", "user_renamed")
```

Comment: * You can query JSON stored as a string by doing text searches but its both slow and very hacky.

Answer (score 0):

use {}.as_json instead of {}.to_json

ex:

```
 a = {}
 a.as_json # => {}
 a.to_json # => "{}"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: Why `.as_json` is better here (or needed at all)?

Comment: For some unknown reason, using `as_json` instead of `to_json` solves the problem.

Comment: @trinopoty: `.as_json` does __nothing__ here. Might as well just drop it and have the same result.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't serialize to JSON as intended. I seem to have overlooked that. My Bad.